# Android Forward Navigation Method

Tags: android, navigation

In Android, there is an `onBackPressed()` code which will navigate back. Is there any way to go forward, like in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no front.  It's a stack-  for you to have returned to a previous activity, finish must have been called on the previous one.  That activity is done, it no longer exists.

Comment: Then is there a way to cache the activity, and start it back?

Comment: You wouldn't start it back, but you could launch the same activity again.  Just keep the activity type last started in a variable (either by name or by keeping it's .class) and call startActivity.  You'll have to track that yourself though.

Comment: Ok. I will make an attempt.